# Rails Find by ID for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I my 2 models in my rails app: Foo and Bar. Bar belongs to Foo and Foo has many Bars. I have a select tag in my form:

```
<%= select_tag(:passed_bar_id, options_for_select(Bar.all.collect{ |i| [i.url, i.id]}), :selected => params[:Bar_id]) %>
```

This works by finding all the "Bars". How would I find the only certain Bars, using a Foo ID to collect then rather than finding the entire collection? What would the extra find syntax be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Foo ID in question is in `:foo_id`:

```
<%= select_tag(:passed_bar_id, options_for_select(Foo.find(:foo_id).bars.collect{ |i| [i.url, i.id]}), :selected => params[:Bar_id]) %>
```

Comment: couldnt this also be done with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Comment: @JohnMerlino Maybe for subsequent assignment when the form is submitted, but `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is for creating and updating attributes, not building forms.